# Pandas - Is it possible to create a column based on boolean values in other columns treating these as variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean-operations

I make myself clear: I want to generate a new column in a hypothetic data frame which can possibly have a different number of columns with boolean values. These "boolean columns" are previously created according to other parameters and they can be 3, 4 or 10 (e.g. k1, k2, k3, k4, etc.).
I know I can set up a code like this:

```
def get_set(row):
if row['k1'] == True:
    return 'k1'
if row['k2'] == True:
    return 'k2'
if row['k3'] == True:
    return 'k3'
if row['k4'] == True:
    return 'k4'
```

and then create the new column:

```
data_frame['Set number'] = data_frame.apply(get_set, axis=1)
```

but what if I need to automatize this process? I mean, I wish to write something that is independent of the number of columns (sets) and works every time giving the sets by input.
I've tried this:

```
def get_set2(row):
discontinuity_set = []
while True:
    n = 'k' + (input('set index: '))
    if n == 'kstop':
        return discontinuity_set
        break
    else:
        discontinuity_set.append(n)
if row[discontinuity_set] == True:
    return discontinuity_set
```

trying to generate a list from which .apply could draw to create the new column, but I get this error message:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

also with a for loop the result is not good.

Does anyone know how this can be possibly done? I really much appreciate any kind of help. Thanks

Comment: Ciao Stefano, do you want it to return the column name for the first  `True` on a row?

Comment: Hi. Actually I need it to return the column name for every True value in the column

Comment: Do it seems to me that you can use masks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to filter the boolean column names, as long as they have a pattern that make them unique from the other columns. Then just pass that to your function when using `DataFrame.apply` (extra keyword arguments are passed onto the function to apply).

```
def get_set(row, names):
    for name in names:
        if row[name] == True:
            return name


boolean_columns = [col for col in data_frame.columns if col.startswith('k')]
data_frame['Set number'] = data_frame.apply(get_set, axis=1, names=boolean_columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

is this helps?

```
df['res'] = False
strings= ['k4','k3','k2','k1']
for key in strings:
    df[df[key ] == true]['res'] = key
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], (4, 5)), 
                 columns = ['k' + str(x) for x in range(5)])
d['something'] = list('ASDE')

def get_set(*args):
    for row in args:
        for i, x in enumerate(row):
            if x : 
                return i
    
d['Set number'] = [d.columns[x]\
                   for x in d\
                       .reindex(sorted(d.columns), axis = 1)\
                        .loc[:, d.columns.str.startswith('k')]\
                        .apply(get_set, axis = 1)]
print(d)

#       k0     k1     k2     k3     k4 something Set number
# 0  False  False   True  False  False         A         k2
# 1  False  False   True   True  False         S         k2
# 2   True   True  False  False  False         D         k0
# 3   True   True  False  False  False         E         k0
```

Comment: if I do:     df['set number'] = [df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('k')].columns[x] for x in df.apply(get_set, axis = 1)]      it doesn't work, because (i don't know why) it gets all sets like 'k1' in the new column

Comment: So I need to create another df with df.loc and then merge it with the original one...that's a bit cumbersome

Comment: not working for me, it gives value 'k1' even if that is False in its column:

Comment: The only reason I could think of, is that the column names are not sorted.

Comment: I get this error with the edited version ------ 

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer